# Disappearing modal on mobile

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am struggling with this since 2 days and I think I tried everything therefore I decided to ask here for help.

I have implemented Ajax login modal according to [this tutorial](http://fellowtuts.com/wordpress/wordpress-ajax-login-and-register-without-a-plugin/) on my website [www.mdbootstrap.com.](http://www.mdbootstrap.com)

While on desktop everything works like a charm, on mobile version modal is disappearing. I can see overlay I thought that it is hiding behind but even when I switch it off I can't see modal. (In order to fire modal click "Download" button and make sure that your'e not logged in)

I tried to debug it in chrome changing different parameter. I made sure that display: is set to block. I also see that non of the property changes between desktop and mobile query. I tried to set it with position absolute, changed size to some ridiculous number to force it to show on the screen but non of that work. I will be helpful for any hint or indication...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code for the modal is inside the HTML of the navbar. Navbar has a `hidden-sm`, which comes from Bootstrap and hides everything when the screen is small. You should put the modal HTML code outside of the navbar. Maybe right behind `<body>` opening tag.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-colored z-depth-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew that I had to miss something....